# Issues with reading and writing an XML file in Java

Tags: java, xml-parsing, domparser

Am using DocumentBuilderFactory to read an XML file and write the same file with different file name. Here's my code :

```
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document dom = db.parse(new InputSource("internal.xml"));

                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(dom);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("newInternal.xml"));
                transformer.transform(source, result);
                System.out.println("File Saved!!!");
```

But am experiencing error in 'newInternal.xml' file. It's saving with '&lt' , '&gt' in the new file. May I know the issue with the above code ?
But it's working fine when I changed the Xml version from 1.1 to 1.0.

Comment: I was able to read and write the Xml file when I changed the xml version to 1.0 from 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct.
On correct XML syntax, you write &lt; to represent a < and &gt; to represent a >.
These escapings exists to ease their utilization, because the characters are used on the XML syntax itself.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters) question has the list of such characters.